# How to know when a MS SQL query returns a RAISERROR in PHP?

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo

I've though that this would work but nothing :(

```
$sql = "RAISERROR('Error.', 16, 1)";
$rs = $conn->query($sql);

if (!$rs) echo 'Error.';
```

What I need it's just a way to know that this query has an error.

I tried this too:

```
try {
    $rs = $conn->query($sql);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'Error';
}
```

Ps. I do have this in the connection:

```
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```